# fetching option values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I new to php and mysql.

I wrote the function below:

```
function catOption() {
$maincatfunc_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainCats ORDER BY id ") or die(mysql_error());
$funcCat = array();
while ($mainCatFunc = mysql_fetch_array($maincatfunc_query)) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($maincatfunc_query); $i++) {



        $funcCat[$i] = '<option value="'.$maincatfunc_sorgu['mainCatID'].'">' . $maincatfunc_sorgu['name'] . '</option>';
    }
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($maincatfunc_query); $i++) {

    return $funcCat[$i];
  }
}
```

I want to fetch "all" value from mysql database and fill it in a dropdown. So i wrote a function like this. But it does not work.

And i don't think count() function doesn't really work in this conditions. How can i get the max count of mysql array ?.

or besides can i do this without using a function ?. I've googled it for a long time but i can't find any usefull info.

Thanks !

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like below: [returns array]

```
function catOption()
{
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainCats ORDER BY id ") or die(mysql_error());
  $arrCat = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $arrCat[] = '<option value="'. $row['mainCatID'].'">'. $row['name'].'</option>';
  }
  return $arrCat;
}
```

Or this one [returns string]

```
function catOption()
{
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainCats ORDER BY id ") or die(mysql_error());
  $arrCat = "";
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $arrCat .= '<option value="'. $row['mainCatID'].'">'. $row['name'].'</option>';
  }
  return $arrCat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this,

```
function catOption() {
    $maincatfunc_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mainCats ORDER BY id ") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($mainCatFunc = mysql_fetch_array($maincatfunc_query)) {

            $funcCat .= '<option value="'.$mainCatFunc['mainCatID'].'">' . $mainCatFunc['name'] . '</option>';

    }
        return $funcCat;
    }
```

Use like this :

```
$dropDownData = catOption();
```

put it into HTML

```
<select><?php echo $dropDownData; ?></select>
```

Comment: You dont need define as `$funcCat = array();`. Returns string